Unable to authenticate request to mongodb from springboot application
I have a problem with a request from my springboot application on mongo (docker), while trying to establish authentication on mongoDB (as soon as I turn it off, the application runs correctly).
Docker mongoDb setting
  mongodb-master:
    image: mongo:6.0.3
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: USERNAME
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: PASS
    hostname: mongodb-master

spring application.yml :
spring:
    data:
        mongodb:
            uri: mongodb://localhost:27017
            database: ${app}
            host: mongodb-master
            password: PASS
            username: USERNAME
            authentication-database: ${app}

final error after request :
"message": "Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command find requires authentication' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {\"ok\": 0.0, \"errmsg\": \"command find requires authentication\", \"code\": 13, \"codeName\": \"Unauthorized\"}"

As I say, when I turn off the request for name and password, the application runs without problems. thanks for any advice
I tried some stackoverflow advice, but I couldn't find anything that would work in my case

Looks like Mongo was not initialized with the database and was not configured with a user/password having the required permissions. Take a look How to create a DB for MongoDB container on start up?. This might get you up and running...
